# How to get easy rules .jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, rule-engine, maven-dependency

I've developed a java web application and now I want to integrate a rule engine as part of this application.

I checked Easy Rules and as mentioned in their website it's just a jar file that I need to add to the project but then in order to get the jar file i need to install meaven and follow number of steps.

**Question**: is there any other way to get the jar file than using maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably [refering](https://github.com/EasyRules/easyrules) to the [following](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.easyrules%7Ceasyrules-core%7C2.3.0%7C) Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easyrules</groupId>
    <artifactId>easyrules-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding this dependency to your Maven project would indeed download the `.jar` file in the local Maven cache and your web application project would then add it to the `lib` of its final `war` file.

However, if you need direct access to the jar file, it is available [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/easyrules/easyrules-core/2.3.0/), that is, the folder view of the Maven Central repository.

Comment: ooh Thanks ! you saved me a day work :D is it easyrules-core-2.3.0.jar  or easyrules-core-2.3.0-sources.jar that I should use?

Comment: The first, the binary. the second is actually the source code.